# STS - Run External Tools Configuration doesn't have java application listed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have created a spring boot app using STS. It does not display "java application" under external tools configuration. Please can you let me know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be under external tools? Look under "Run As" context menu and find "Run As >> Spring Boot App". That's what you should use to run it.